# transferring consciousness from one person to another person?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, medicine, anatomy, brain

Is the transferring of "consciousness" from one person to another person is  possible if a brain transplantation is possible ?

Is it possible to pick memories from the brain by using EEG?

Comment: Too many questions in one post. Please limit to one clearly stated problem per post. Also, since we currently are not able to transplant brains, which kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If your brain would be transplanted into another body](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25526/if-your-brain-would-be-transplanted-into-another-body)

Comment: #L.Dutch  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/30492/l-dutch.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *HARI*! You can notify a user by writing an "@" in front of their username. It even autocompletes. You can notify one user per comment and the OP is always notified. Your question does indeed look like a duplicate to the question mentioned. Especially the highest voted answer seems to answer the question by stating that we just don't really know and so everything is basically up to you and your story. Could you [edit] to make the difference to the other question more clear? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: I remember that I drank coffee yesterday. I just transferred a memory from me to you. Magical, isn't it? We already have the tool, it is called language. For better examples, well, there are a lot of people writing autobiographies. Maybe read one of them.  Yes, if one wants to fully transfer a particular memory with all it's details to someone, one would have to talk a lot maybe, but it's possible in principal.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I think more context on why would somebody "extract" memories from brains is needed (torture, memory from a dead person,...). OP should edit it's question....

Comment: @Raditz_35 transferring memories like autobiographies seems to have only memories. my way of thinking is why cant one live a long life after our time period is over. my wish is to see the world till it ends. i Am feared of dying or may be i am feared of leaving my girl and my parent so if there is possibility i can make use of this to live a long life by a robot or by developing a clone of my own and continue my living in that and shall proceed it for years and years ?

Comment: @Goufalite not from a dead person. like i said is it possible to access memories of a person from brain through EEG

Comment: @HARI A brain transplant does not transfer memories from one person to another person. It transfers one **person** from one **body** to another body, memories, instincts, thoughts and all.

Comment: @MichaelK does that really happens. is it possible ? does any article about it exist ?

Comment: @HARI Brain transplants are presently not possible, no. But since all memories are contained in the brain, moving the brain from one body to another **obviously** brings along the memories. Along with personality, knowledge and all other such mental faculties.

Comment: @MichaelK thank you so much. hoping to write an article in this topic as i had doubts i clarified now.

Answer (score 2):

Since the two first questions are covered by the dupe question, let's answer the EEG part.

A quick google gives me [this article](https://www.theverge.com/2016/1/12/10754436/commercial-eeg-headsets-video-games-mind-control-technology) :

> **It's important to remember that EEG can't actually read a person's thoughts**. Instead, it connects neuronal patterns with actions or mental states. "If I move my right hand, and that creates a very clear signal that links to a computer command, that’s an entirely different beast than me simply wanting my character in the game to turn left and turn right"

Of course we understand want you want to do but it is quite risky especially in a real world situation (in a fiction work you can do anything). For example in S03E01 of *Rick and Morty*, Rick is trapped in a simulation where an entity wants it to *remember* a specific part of his life where he writes a crucial math equation. Rick tricks the entity by creating a false memory (writing another equation).

You can very easily manipulate memories on people, making them **think** something happened, especially with peer pressure ("hey I remember that too!").

In conclusion, in a real situation it is quite impossible since memories are not reliable. But in a fiction work you can handwave any futuristic/magical device that can isolate a fresh memory.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/26078/goufalite

Comment: tat was satisfying since it disturbed my mind for a while.